# How to overlay a shape on a video in p5js?

Tags: javascript, video, p5.js, shapes

In P5js I want to overlay a shape to a video, but they don't share the same dom element.
Is there any way to do it?

[Code test here](https://editor.p5js.org/nemecsek/sketches/_cOUl-3Xo): The video should be visible through the triangular contour that cuts the shape.

The code:

```js
let video;

function preload() {
  video = createVideo("video.mp4");
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 300);
  background("gray");

  video.size(400,400);
  video.loop();
  
  var w = width * 0.7;
  var h = height * 0.7;

  translate((width/2) - (w/2), (height/2) - (h/2));

  fill("lightgray");
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
    vertex(0, 0);
    vertex(w, 0);
    vertex(w, h);
    vertex(0, h);
    beginContour();
      vertex(w * 0.2, h * 0.4);
      vertex(w * 0.5, h * 0.8);
      vertex(w * 0.8, h * 0.4);
    endContour();
  endShape();

  noLoop();
}
```

I see [here](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-canvas.html) that hiding the video and using `image` (i.e. `image(video, 10, 10)`) it is possible to draw a single frame. Alas I use `noLoop()` and in my case there would be no automatic refresh of the video in `draw()`.

Comment: "they don't share the same dom' -- I don't follow. In this sketch, everything seems to be in the same DOM. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ggorlen, sorry, my mistake, I skipped a word: "they don't share the same dom ELEMENT". They show up in different dom elements.

Comment: Thanks -- you might want to [edit] the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The video should be visible through the triangular contour that cuts the shape."*

Below is a result I got from a quick play-around with your code. 
Maybe it will be useful to you in some way (*eg:* gives new ideas on how to proceed).

The code's logic is to simply create 2 layers. 
Bottom layer 1 is **video** and top layer 2 is triangle (the **canvas**).

Other ideas include maybe using BlendModes like Screen or Multiply:
example: `canv.blendMode(SCREEN);`
Where `SCREEN` makes whites transparent, and `MULTIPLY` makes blacks transparent).

The example testing code (makes two layers and also removed `background("gray");`)

```
let video; let canv;

function preload() 
{ video = createVideo("video.mp4"); }

function setup() 
{
  translate(0, 0);
  
  video.size(400,300);
  video.style("z-index: 1"); //# is default in P5.JS
  video.position(0, (width * 0.7) );
  video.loop();
  
  canv = createCanvas(400, 400);
  canv.style("z-index: 2");
  canv.position(0, 0); //# important to have a setting
  
  //# Not needed ....
  //background("gray");
  
  var w = width * 1;
  var h = height * 1;
   
  translate((width/2) - (w/2), (height/2) - (h/2));

  fill("lightgray");
  noStroke();
  
  beginShape();
    vertex(0, 0);
    vertex(w, 0);
    vertex(w, h);
    vertex(0, h);
  
 beginContour();
      vertex(w * 0.2, h * 0.4);
      vertex(w * 0.5, h * 0.8);
      vertex(w * 0.8, h * 0.4);
    endContour();
  endShape();

  noLoop();
}
```